# Setting global variables with macOS Catalina

Tags: environment-variables

I use the `environment.plist` method to setup global variables in macOS.
I have this template in `~/Library/LaunchAgents`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
    <dict>
        <key>Label</key>
        <string>setenv.XDG</string>
        <key>Program</key>
        <string>/bin/zsh</string>
        <key>ProgramArguments</key>
        <array>
            <string>/bin/zsh</string>
            <string>-c</string>
            <string>
                launchctl setenv FOO BAR;
            </string>
        </array>
        <key>RunAtLoad</key>
        <true/>
    </dict>
</plist>
```

It works.

But: when I restart my computer, I need to open `Terminal.app` and close it at least once or the variables will not be available to GUI apps.

How shall I change that setup to skip opening Terminal.app after a reboot?

Comment: Does `zsh` not use `set`/ `setenv` command to set environment variables ? https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/368944/what-is-the-difference-between-env-setenv-export-and-when-to-use

Comment: Why did @nohillside remove my second question?

Comment: Sorry, forgot to add a comment. Please ask only one question per post, otherwise it's difficult to get good answers. You can always ask further questions in new posts.

Comment: @ankii this is about using `launchctl` to set global environment variables, the shell shouldn't matter.